# Authentication using ios keychain - touch id (is this possible)

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

Instead of using the user object and password from ios keychain to authenticate in an app do developers have access to the user object's touchId.  I do not want to store the fingerprint (and I know that apple will not allow this) I just want to authenticate using the fingerprint (touchid) that is encrypted on the hardware.  I can't seem to find any subclasses or methods in the documentation that would allow me to perform the authentication using touchId rather than user and pass. Any insight would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no public API yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, (at the time of writing) developers have no access to the touch sensor or any information from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if you jailbreak.